# Trigger not firing after insert through Entity Framework in ASP.NET MVC 4

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, sql-server-2014

I have a C# application using Entity Framework and I created a trigger in the database to fire after insert and update.

I notice that the trigger does not fire when I insert or update using EF code, on the other side the trigger fires when I insert or update through SQL Server.

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[UpdatePRCWax_Status]
ON [dbo].[PRCWax]
FOR INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE
AS 
    DECLARE @CountPRCQty_Wax int 
    DECLARE @CountPRCQty int
    DECLARE @WaxStatus int 
    DECLARE @PRCStatus int 

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @ChkPRCNO varchar(12)

    SET @ChkPRCNo = (SELECT PRCNO FROM Inserted)

    SELECT @CountPRCQty_Wax = SUM(QTY1 + QTY2), @WaxStatus = Min(STATUS) 
    FROM PRCWax 
    WHERE (PRCNO = @ChkPRCNo)

    SELECT @PRCStatus = ISNULL(STATUS, 0), @CountPRCQty = PQTY 
    FROM PRC 
    WHERE (PRCNO = @ChkPRCNo)

    IF @CountPRCQty_Wax >= @CountPRCQty AND @WaxStatus = 0 AND @PRCStatus = 1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE PRCWax 
        SET Status = 1 
        WHERE (PRCNO = @ChkPRCNo)

        UPDATE PRC 
        SET Status = 10 
        WHERE (PRCNO = @ChkPRCNo)
    END

    IF @CountPRCQty_Wax >= @CountPRCQty AND @WaxStatus = 0 AND @PRCStatus > 1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE PRCWax 
        SET Status = 1 
        WHERE (PRCNO = @ChkPRCNo)
    END

    IF @CountPRCQty_Wax >= @CountPRCQty AND @WaxStatus = 1 AND @PRCStatus = 1
    BEGIN
        UPDATE PRC 
        SET Status = 10 
        WHERE (PRCNO = @ChkPRCNo)
    END

    IF @CountPRCQty_Wax < @CountPRCQty AND @WaxStatus = 1 AND @PRCStatus = 10
    BEGIN
        UPDATE PRCWax 
        SET Status = 0 
        WHERE (PRCNO = @ChkPRCNo)   

        UPDATE PRC 
        SET Status = 1 
        WHERE (PRCNO = @ChkPRCNo)
    END
END
```

My controller code for insert is like this

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProcessWax(PRCWax w)
{
    PRCWaxSub ps = new PRCWaxSub();
    var res = Db.PRCWaxSubs.Where(x => x.PRCNO.Trim().ToLower() == w.PRCNO.Trim().ToLower() && x.DT == w.DT).FirstOrDefault();

    if (res == null)
    {
        ps.DT = w.DT;
        ps.PRCNO = w.PRCNO;
        ps.Qty1 = w.QTY1;
        ps.RejQty1 = w.REJECTQTY1;
        ps.EID = w.EID;
        ps.MachineID = w.MachineSrNo;
        Db.PRCWaxSubs.Add(ps);
        var result = Db.SaveChanges();

        return Json(result, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    else
    {
        var spres = Db.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("Set DateFormat DMY update PRCWaxSub Set Qty1=Qty1+" + w.QTY1 + ", RejQty1=RejQty1+" + w.REJECTQTY1 + ",EID=" + w.EID + ",MachineID=" + w.MachineSrNo + " WHERE PRCNO = '" + w.PRCNO + "' and  (DATEDIFF(D, DT, '" + w.DT + "')= 0)");
        var result = Db.SaveChanges();
        return Json(spres, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Why this is happening can anyone have solution?

Please help me - thank you in advance

Comment: What is your trigger trying to achieve here? Why is it on `DELETE` (and `UPDATE`) when you never reference the `deleted` object? Why does it assume that a DML statement will only ever affect 1 row, when it can effect many.

Comment: no sir it will only affect one row at a time because there is a primary key validation so and primary key on a date field as well.

Comment: A primary key doesn't stop an `INSERT` provided 2+ rows...